# Gluons, the Weak Force, or both?

Tags: quarks, gluons, weak-interaction

I've recently been reading about how the Weak Force holds quarks together to make protons and neutrons. But before learning about that specifically, I found out about Quark-Gluon Plasma, leading me to learn that *gluons* hold quarks together in protons and neutrons. Other websites say that both of the two work together, or that gluons themselves hold the weak force. Which of these, if any, is right?

Comment: Here is a table for which forces act on which particles in the standard model: http://phycomp.technion.ac.il/~webteach/phys3/ph114053/adler/forces.jpg. This doesn't mean that there are no other interactions, it only means that we haven't been able to detect them, yet, should they exist.

Answer (score 5):

Gluons are the bosons associated with the strong nuclear force.  The particles W and Z are the bosons associated with weak nuclear force. The strong nuclear force holds quarks together to make nucleons.

Answer (score 1):

The weak force does not hold protons and neutron together. What the weak force does is undergo radioactive decay. The bosons responsible or W-,W+, and Z bosons. Gluons are responsible for the strong force. Strong force holds quarks together and also hold protons with neutrons.